# Haskell: detect changes in uncontrolled CSV flat file

Tags: list, haskell, comparison, difference

I'm developing an application which will read data from zero or more CSV files, which I'll refer-to as 'external' data.  The application will maintain derived ('internal') data in its own (SQLite) tables, associated with the 'rows' (lines) in the external data so that the user can insert, delete or change lines and the derived data will still be associated with the same row.  If the external data were a Postgres table, I could use the row OID to link/join the 'external' with the 'internal' data.  There is a 1:1 correspondence between internal and external rows.

So when the application starts, it will read the external file.  If a row has been deleted, the corresponding internal row will be deleted.  If a row has been added, a new row will be added to the internal data.  If a row has been changed, the internal data will remain, unchanged.  There is no 'key' field in the external data that can be assumed not to change.

Now this is a bit heuristic but as I said, I'd like to be able to detect CRUD in the external CSV, so what I thought was to calculate a 256-bit CRC 'fingerprint' for each external row, and store that in the internal SQLite table.  Then when the application starts, it has both an internal and external **[Integer]** which it can compare somewhat like the GNU/Unix/Linux *diff* program to detect minor changes in the external file.  I do want two separate tables:  I want to allow users to supply the 'external' CSV, and change it, but I want to control what is in the 'internal' table.

I would expect the external data to be of the order of a few hundred lines;  say 1000 at most.

So my question is:  is there any library that would heuristically compare the two fingerprint **[Integer]** and output a minimal difference list in terms of add, delete and change ?  or anything in that direction ?

As a supplementary, it would be nice to have a relatively stable fingerprint algorithm;  i.e., one whose output changed only slightly with a slightly-changed input, but that's less important than the main question, above.

Answer (score 1):

My advice: don't bother fingerprinting. Use the [Diff](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Diff) package; you can specify a cost for any single-record change and it will find the minimal-cost overall change (subject to the usual diff restrictions: no re-ordering, etc.).

If you want to support reordering, you lose efficiency big-time, but it can still be done.

Comment: Thanks but I would have to support re-ordering.  As I'm sure you are well aware, there's no telling what users will do.  ;-)

Comment: @Michael I don't believe there is an existing package to do set-based diffs, so you'll have to write that code yourself. The first part of my advice stands. Per the experience reports with [boomerang](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~harmony/), you may want to set a maximum threshold across which two records will never be aligned. Unless there is actually extra data associated with each record that does not appear in the CSV file, you should also consider simply replacing your in-memory database wholesale, without trying any trickery.

Comment: I wonder if, properly parameterised, a such package would be a useful contribution to the community.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Diff-0.3.1/docs/Data-Algorithm-Diff.html goes part-way to what I want.